# Null Values in Checkbox Custom Fields

Tags: clio-api

I'm noticing that editing a matter from the web interface and adding a checkbox custom field to the matter does not automatically set that checkbox to 'false.' Instead, unless you set the box to true, save it, and then re-edit it to uncheck that box, you cannot get a subsequent api call to return a 'false' value.

It strikes me that this ought to be corrected?

Answer (score 0):

This is Matt G. from Clio's API support team.

You're correct that checkbox custom fields don't return a false value unless thy're actually toggled on and then off. Until some value is set, the checkbox field won't have any information stored in it and will return a null value.

We'll evaluate the functionality and look into updating how checkboxes work. In the meantime, if you want to get records of all Matters with an unchecked checkbox,  you can look for Custom Field Values that are false and null.